# Usages of "excess weight"

Tags: sentence-meaning

When the following sentence can be asked:

> - How much excess weight do you have?

a) When e.g. someone wants to know about your weight e.g. to recommend you how to avoid being more fat.
b) When an officer in an airport wants to calculate your luggage weight.

Asking this question I want to know if the sentence above can be used in both of those senses 'a' and 'b' or not?

Comment: If I said that to a woman I would probably get hit...

Comment: I exactly know that @user3169; :D But I was wondering if you could answer the my question which I asked from @LMS?

Comment: Spoken to someone, it would be better to say what that person "should" or "need" to lose, and framed in some context that is beneficial to that person (why it would be a good idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Excess weight* will generally always refer to cargo, luggage, and similar things. Specifically, how much over the prescribed weight limit your cargo/luggage is: if the weight allowance is 25kg and you bring 29kg, you have 4kg of excess weight. You can also use *overweight* to describe something that is over the weight limit.

If someone is fatter than is healthy, they would be *overweight* or, in more extreme cases, *obese*. These terms do have formal definitions, but in conversation that doesn't particularly matter. If you're curious, according to the World Health Organisation "overweight" is a [body mass index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index) (BMI) of 25-30kg/m<sup>2</sup> and "obese" is a BMI of or greater than 30kg/m<sup>2</sup>. The m<sup>2</sup> part is the height of the person squared.

If you were to enquire about someone's weight, you might ask:

> How much do you weigh? *(in kilograms/pounds/stone/etc)*
>   What do you weigh?
>   How heavy are you?

I imagine many people would take offence at it (these options are less than polite), but you could also ask:

> How overweight are you?
>   How fat are you?

Someone may also take offence at the first three options, but the last two are significantly more inflammatory.

---

> **Further question:**
>   Let's suppose the person who refers to a doctor / trainer comes back e.g. home and his / her sister, spouse tends to know about the amount of his / her extra weight which has been recognized by the physician / trainer; then is it possible for them to ask, "how much extra weight / excess weight do you have?" (based on the recognition of e.g. your doctor / trainer)

If you had a set target to reach (perhaps you weigh 110kg and your doctor recommends you to reduce that to 80kg), you could ask about the target:

> How close are you? (to the target)
>   How far off are you? (from the target)
>   How much weight do you have to lose?

You could answer each of those with:

> I need to lose 30kg.
>   I have 30kg left to lose.
>   I'm 30kg off my target.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a great answer @LMS; But let's suppose the person who refers to a doctor / trainer comes back e.g. home and his /  her sister, spouse tends to know about the amount of his / her extra weight which has been recognized by the physician / trainer; then is it possible for them to ask, "how much extra weight / excess weight do you have?" (based on the recognition of e.g. your doctor / trainer)

Comment: @A-friend: I've edited my answer. I hope my addition clarifies for you.

Comment: Great; Thanks a million @LMS; it was a really helpful guide...